# How to select first day and last day of the week when we select any date in dojox.calendar.?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using a custom dojox.calendar. currently if I select any date I am able to get the date. Now,How to select first day and last day of the week when we select any date in dojox.calendar.?

Comment: Is the first day of the week Sunday or Monday? Is the last day Friday, Saturday or Sunday?

Comment: first day is sunday  and last day us saturday..!!

Comment: Ok, so do you need a function that, given a date, returns a date for the Sunday before at 00:00:00 and the Saturday after at 23:59:59? You can then use that to create a range in the Dojox calendar.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a small function that, given a Date object and week day number, returns the previous day of the same [week day number](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.6) (Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, …, Saturday = 6).

```
function getPreviousDay(date, day) {
    var d = new Date(+date);
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - ((7 + d.getDay() - day) % 7));
    return d;
}

console.log(getPreviousDay(new Date(2013,11,24), 2)); // Tue 17-Dec-2013
```

If the Date is a Tuesday and the week day number is 2, it will return a copy of the supplied Date. This can be used to build functions that, given a Date, return the previous Sunday and next Saturday:

```
// If date is Sunday, return a copy of date (default for getPreviousDay)
// Otherwise, get previous Sunday
function getPreviousSunday(date) {
  var d = getPreviousDay(date, 0);
  return d;
}

// If date is Saturday, return a copy of date
// Otherwise, get previous Saturday and add 7 days
function getNextSaturday(date) {
  if (date.getDay() == 6) {
    return new Date(+date);
  }
  var d = getPreviousDay(date, 6);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
  return d;
}

var d = new Date(2013,11,21);

console.log(
  d + '\n' +
  getPreviousSunday(d) + '\n' +
  getNextSaturday(d)
);

/*
   Sat 21-Dec-2013
   Sun 15-Dec-2013
   Sat 21-Dec-2013 
*/
```

Those values can then be used to select a date range in the calendar.

I use `new Date(+date)` to copy dates because otherwise in the years 0 to 99, IE will assume 1900 to 1999 and mess up the copy. While it's unlikely you'll want to use dates in this range (pretty pointless really) it makes me feel better knowing that it will "work" if you do.

IE does this because if a Date object is passed to the Date constructor, it is [first converted to a string](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2), then the string parsed to create a Date object. IE incorrectly parses its own string for years 0 to 99. Using `+` converts the date to a time value, which is treated correctly by the Date constructor everywhere (as far as I know).